# Using RequireJS with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, requirejs, angular5

Is there any guide anywhere to use Angular 5 with requireJS?
I'm trying to insert an Angular5 app into an AngularJS ngView (route of route)

**index.html**

```
<div ng-if="showView" ng-view class="container"></div>

    // routes
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "mainController",
            controllerAs: "main",
            resolve: {
                dummy: function ($rootScope) {
                    require(["angular_ctrl"], function () {
                        console.info("HOME DEPS LOADED!!");
                        $rootScope.showView = true;
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        //ANGULAR 5 CONTENT
        .when("/delivery", {
            templateUrl: "_delivery/dist/delivery.html",
            resolve: {
                dummy: function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.showView = true;
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/home"
        });
```

The issue I'm facing is that if I leave the generated angular5 index as is, **the app is fine the first time I enter the delivery route**, but from the second time I get the following error:

> zone already loaded

So I created **_delivery/dist/delivery.html** (instead of _delivery/dist/index.html) with the following content:

```
<base href="">
<app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var angularFiveDeps = [
        "_delivery/dist/inline.bundle.js",
        "_delivery/dist/polyfills.bundle.js",
        "_delivery/dist/styles.bundle.js",
        "_delivery/dist/vendor.bundle.js",
        "_delivery/dist/main.bundle.js"
    ];

    require(angularFiveDeps, function () {
        console.info("DELIVERY DEPS LOADED!!");

    });
</script>
```

But I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Thank you